# store and use select statement result in stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to store the results of a select query in a stored proc and then use those results from within the stored proc to further query the result set?

**Example
// my stored proc (simplified example)**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[users]  
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @users nvarchar(1000)            

        set @users = select * from users


    // query @users result for counts, sums where clauses, etc...


END
```

Comment: You've not really given an example, yet, of why you can't write this as a single query...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `users` to be a table variable or temp table instead of an nvarchar type.

Table Variable Version

```
DECLARE @users TABLE (
    UserId int,
    ...
)

INSERT INTO @users
    (UserId, ...)
    SELECT *
        FROM users

SELECT *
    FROM AnotherTable t
        INNER JOIN @users u
            ON ...
```

Temp Table Version

```
CREATE TABLE #users (
    UserId int,
    ...
)

INSERT INTO #users
    (UserId, ...)
    SELECT *
        FROM users

SELECT *
    FROM AnotherTable t
        INNER JOIN #users u
            ON ...
```

You could also implicitly create the temp table.

```
SELECT *
    INTO #users
    FROM users

SELECT *
    FROM AnotherTable t
        INNER JOIN #users u
            ON ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @users TABLE (...columns...);
INSERT @users SELECT * FROM dbo.Users;
```

Though depending on the number of rows, a #temp table can often be safer because it will have statistics, you can create additional indexes, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #users (...columns...);
INSERT #users SELECT * FROM dbo.Users;
```

Comment: Um, table variables exist in [2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260638(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: You're right, my memory is bad, they were introduced in 2000. Must just be habit - most of the cool features were added in 2005. Would be great though if SO forced users tagging with sql-server to also tag with at least one specific version - I really detest having to guess or ask.

Comment: They were introduced in 2000. See: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305977](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305977)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agree with you on the version tags. I've answered a few questions with a CTE, ROW_NUMBER, etc. only to have the OP come back and say "Sorry, I'm using 2000."

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temp table or a table variable to do just that. Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx) comparing the options.